# Django AbstractUser Not Allowing Field Data To Be Saved

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model object that extends the User Object with AbstractUser to add fields. However, with a html form I am not able to save anything to those fields. In addition, when I try to save in the shell, I can not save if the field is in a list...but I can save if the field is taken outside of a list. I am using Django 1.6 with Postgres. This is driving me crazy.

*The issue is only when the model is using `AbstractUser`, normal models are not having this issue.*

```
class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2 control-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-4'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset('Account Modify',
                'irc_name',
                'forum_username',
                ),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary')
                )
            )


class Employee(AbstractUser):
    irc_name = models.CharField(max_length="25")
    forum_username = models.CharField(max_length="25")


class AccountModify(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = AccountForm
    template_name = 'bot_data/account_modify.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

Shell Session:

```
>>> foo = Employee.objects.all()
>>> foo[1]
<Employee: dar777>
>>> foo[1].irc_name
u''
>>> foo[1].irc_name = "Steve"
>>> foo[1].irc_name
u''
>>> bar = foo[1]
>>> bar
<Employee: dar777>
>>> bar.irc_name
u''
>>> bar.irc_name = "Steve"
>>> bar.irc_name
'Steve'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you slicing queryset django get you new instance of `in memory object`

```
foo = Employee.objects.all()
foo[1] -> new instance 
foo[1].irc_name = 1234 -> new instance
foo[1].save()
print foo[1].irc_name -> will print u''
```

The best practice is to avoid slicing of queryset. You can find full answer in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_ziKY1ayCo#t=1923 (binding to time)

Comment: ok, but still have a the issue of not being able to save using html form

Comment: try to save form from shell

Comment: I can from shell succesfully with no issues.